# Prompt shared users to install app

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive SDK and I made a simple app with a sharing feature. Unfortunately, when a document is shared with a user who doesn't have my app installed, they are prompted with the following message:

```
You do not have StoryPad installed
This item was created with StoryPad, a Google Drive app you have not installed.
```

However they don't see a link or an option to install this app. Is there a way to configure it so that they are prompted to install on this screen? I don't want users to have to hunt around looking for a way to install this app because they will leave.

Here is a screenshot of how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Have you checked to see if this is the answer you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Google Drive SDK documentation, in the [error handling section](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors), it seems if you trap the error:

```
 `403: The authenticated user has not installed the app with client id {clientId}
 The user has not installed the requesting app, or has uninstalled it.`
```

The documented suggested action is to:

```
 Direct the user to the Chrome Web Store to install the app.
```

You don't list which language you're working with, so an example (other languages are listed on the above referenced page as well) in JavaScript could be:

```
request.execute(function(resp) {
    if (!resp.error) {

      //Excellent, everything is working correctly! Proceed to show your file.

    } else {

      console.log('Error code: ' + resp.error.code);

      if (resp.error.reason == "appNotInstalled") {

        //Here is where you implement the action to inform the user where to download your app.
        alert("You need to install StoryBoard to view this file! Please proceed here: http://<link to your app>");

      }

      // More error information can be retrieved with resp.error.errors.
    }
});
```

Comment: This isn't precisely what I was looking for but accepted because I wasn't specific enough. The dialog you see up there is seen from within the Google Drive browser itself. This is before your app is even loaded.

Comment: Ah.. Okay. Thank you for awarding the bounty!